# windows form application

Tags: windows, forms

I have a code in c++ of binary search trees
and I want to use this code in a new windows form app.
Could any one help me how can I do that.
Thanks.

Comment: sorry but i want ageneral rule about(how to include my code to windows forms application)
i mean if i had a code in c++
how can i include it's output and input to make windows to my code


thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search is already built in to the .NET framework.

VB:

```
 Dim foo As New Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)
 foo.BinarySearch(3)
```

C#:

```
List<Integer> foo = new List<Integer>();
foo.BinarySearch(3);
```

You could also write a C++ based WinForm if you want to write everything in C++...